# Passing closure/ blocks in array as parameter iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures

I am trying to pass alert actions in array to a function that is used to simplify the UIAlertController configuration into one single line. 
Am able to successfully pass button titles but not the alert actions. 
Here is what i am doing.

```
+(void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString*)title 
                  message:(NSString*)alertmessage 
             buttonTitles:(NSArray*)buttonTitles 
            buttonActions:(NSArray*)buttonActions 
         inViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController {

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:alertmessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [buttonTitles enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* buttonTitle,NSUInteger idx,BOOL *stop){
         UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:buttonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler: [[buttonActions objectAtIndex:idx] copy]]; //blocks should always be copied to heap from stack else they will crash
        [alert addAction:action];
    }];

    [viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The above code file was written long back so its in objective c. 
I have written some new files which are in swift and i am calling the above method in swift as below.

```
 CommonManager.showAlert(withTitle: "", message: "Feedback Sent", 
       buttonTitles: ["Ok"], buttonActions: [ { (action: UIAlertAction) in

                    print("you pressed Ok alert button");

                    // call method whatever u need
                }], in: self)
```

If i dont pass the closure it works fine, if passing the closure when clicking on Ok it crashes. 
I also found that we need to copy a block when its passed as a collection and i did that but something is still not right which am not able to figure out. Can you tell me what i need to do here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a Swift closure is a different kind of object than an Objective-C block, so trying to run it as a block crashes.

Normally if the Swift compiler sees that you are passing a closure to an Objective-C method with a block type parameter, it will convert the Swift closure to an Objective-C block, but in this case, it just sees you are putting it in an array, and not about what the method will do to it inside the array, so it doesn't do any conversion.

The only way I can figure out to get it to work is something like this:

```
 CommonManager.showAlert(withTitle: "", message: "Feedback Sent", 
       buttonTitles: ["Ok"], buttonActions: [ { (action: UIAlertAction) in

                    print("you pressed Ok alert button");

                    // call method whatever u need
                } as (@convention(block) (UIAlertAction) -> Void)!], in: self)
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than dealing with conversion weirdness, why not just make a native swift version?

Here's my version of the same functionality:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func presentAlert(title: String, message: String, actions: [UIAlertAction] = [UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)], iPadOrigin: CGRect? = nil, style: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert, animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
        actions.forEach(alert.addAction)
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        if let iPadOrigin = iPadOrigin {
            alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = iPadOrigin
        }

        present(alert, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }

    func presentAlert(title: String, message: String, actions: [UIAlertAction] = [UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)], iPadButtonOrigin: UIBarButtonItem? = nil, style: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert, animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: style)
        actions.forEach(alert.addAction)
        alert.view.tintColor = Color.BlueDarker
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = iPadButtonOrigin

        present(alert, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

It also handles iPad differences and some nice defaults so you could just do `viewController.presentAlert(title: "Error", message: "Something broke")` if you want a simple alert on iPhone.